# how to exclude a special condition when using group by and count()

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count

In a transaction table, has order_ID(PK), transaction_date, cus_ID, store_ID.
Now I need to get all the cus_ID with when group by cus_ID, count(store_ID) = 1. There is one exception though - When cus_ID has only orders with store_ID='999'. 
Transaction date should be during the past 365 days. 
I have code as below:

```
Select cus_ID, count(store_ID) as store_count
From trn_header
where transanction_date From '7/30/2017' - 365 To '7/30/2017'
group by cus_ID having store_count = 1
```

I just don't know how to exclude the '999' condition...
thanks

Comment: When `store_ID='999'` then what? It *sounds* like you need a `CASE` statement but I am not understanding your logic.

Comment: if one cust_id has all his orders as store_ID = '999', it should be excluded by my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer should be like this:

```
select distinct cus_id, store_id from
(select cus_id,count(distinct store_id) as freq
from a
where transaction_date between @begin_date and @end_date
group by cus_id
having count(distinct store_id) = 1
) b, a where a.cus_id = b.cus_id and store_id <> '999'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select cus_ID, count(store_ID) as store_count
From trn_header
where transanction_date From '7/30/2017' - 365 To '7/30/2017' And store_ID<>'999'
group by cus_ID having store_count = 1
```

hope it can be helpful

Comment: Figured it out as I should use sub-query to exclude the store_id ='999' case; there is misunderstanding from my question. Sorry about that.